# Anagram Python 3

Tags: python, anagram

How can I write a function that checks whether 2 inputs are anagrams?

```
word1 = input("Enter a string: ")
word2 = input("Enter a second string: ")

def isAnagram(s1, s2):
    s1 = word1.sort()
    s2 = word2.sort()
    if s1 == s2:
       print("This is an anagram")
    else:
       print("This is not an anagram)
isAnagram()
```

Comment: 1. I think you need to google the definition of anagram. 2. This is a zillionth question here about an anagram program in python and I'm sure you'll find more than enough hints around. 3. SO is for specific questions, not for "fix my code" ones.

Comment: 4. You never accepted any answers to your questions. This makes people yet more reluctant to answer. If you found what you were looking for, accept the answer and/or upvote other helpful answers.

Comment: @sashkello: He seems to understand anagrams just fine. His algorithm is correct, and even reasonably efficient. He just doesn't understand some basic Python stuff.

Comment: @abarnert Yep, I see it now, misread code at first. Basic search skills would come useful though, here is what I found within 20 seconds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990725/checking-strings-against-each-other-anagrams/14990938#14990938

Comment: Thanks everybody. @sashkello you're right, I did a little more googling and found some more help. I think I was just frustrated that I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: The very basic idea to solve anagram is to sort both string than equate them. If they are equal than its an anagram otherwise not. A simple python implementation can be found http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/06/python-anagram-program.html

Comment: This question should be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990725.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined the function almost correctly, but there are a few problems.

First you're asking for `s1` and `s2` as parameters. That's good. Now use those values, not the globals `word1` and `word2`.

Second, if those values are strings, you can't call `sort` on them, because strings don't have a `sort` method. But you can call the `sorted` function on *any* sequence, even strings.

Third, there's a simple typo, a missing `"` on the second `print`.

It might be better to return a True or False value, and put the `print` outside the function, but let's leave that for now.

Putting that together, here's a working function:

```
def isAnagram(s1, s2):
    s1 = sorted(s1)
    s2 = sorted(s2)
    if s1 == s2:
       print("This is an anagram")
    else:
       print("This is not an anagram")
```

But now, you have to *call* the function properly, too. You've defined the function to take two parameters, `s1` and `s2`. That means you need to call the function with two arguments.

So, where do you get those arguments? Well, you've already got those variables `word1` and `word2` sitting around, and they seem like exactly what you want.

So, change the last line to:

```
isAnagram(word1, word2)
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to finding anagrams is perfectly reasonable. Sorting the words and comparing them is the easiest way to find if two words are anagrams of one another.

However, I think you're confused by the idea of function parameters. When you define

```
foo(x1, x2)
```

when `foo` is called, it is expected to be called with 2 parameters. You define

```
anagram(s1, s2)
```

but never supply it with s1 and s2. The parameter list is not a list of variable names that you use in the function -- you can assign new variables at will. Instead, it is the list of inputs that the function takes.

so, `anagram()` is incorrect. You need to call `anagram(input1, input2)`. (Assuming you don't have default values, which I won't get into.

```
def isAnagram(s1, s2):
    sortedWord1 = sorted(s1) # s1 is word1! (sorted instead of sort, strings are immutable)
    #what should you do here?
    if sortedWord1 == sortedWord2:
       print("This is an anagram")
    else:
       print("This is not an anagram") # you forgot a closing quote!

word1 = input("Enter a string: ")
word2 = input("Enter a second string: ")

isAnagram(word1, word2)
```

I changed your code very slightly such that it should do the right thing. I recommend that you read up on [functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) a bit more before you continue, though.

Think of them just like functions in math! `f(x)` is meaningful, `f`, while still meaningful, is probably not what you were looking for.

```
>>> isAnagram("anagram", "nagaram")
This is an an anagram
>>> isAnagram("anagram", "woohoo")
This is not an anagram
>>> isAnagram("a", "a")
This is an an anagram
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea, but since `word1` and `word2` are strings, they don't have the `.sort()` attribute. You can still sort the letters within that string:

```
>>> w='hello'
>>> sorted(w)
['e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

The result of `sorted()` is a list, we can turn it back to a string my joining them using an empty string:

```
>>> ''.join(sorted(w))
'ehllo'
```

Armed with this knowledge, your program might look something like:

```
word1 = input("Enter a string: ")
word2 = input("Enter a second string: ")

def isAnagram(s1, s2):
    s1 = ''.join(sorted(word1))
    s2 = ''.join(sorted(word2))
    if s1 == s2:
       print("This is an anagram")
    else:
       print("This is not an anagram")

isAnagram(word1, word2)
```