# Python check for Anagram in O(n) solution

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if 2 strings are anagrams. This solution is simple, but not efficient (Ologn) I know I could use Collections and Counter, then compare the occurrence of each character, but I'm trying to avoid any modules for an interview. What would be the fastest way to solve this problem? (Perhaps, checking occurrence of each character?)

```
def check(word1,word2):

    return sorted(word1)==sorted(word2)
```

Comment: Fast isn't even the issue here. Your code has multiple bugs in it, making it think "car" and "cat" are anagrams.

Comment: `if sorted(l1) == sorted(l2)` is , depending on how `sort` is done, probably `O(nlogn)`

Comment: @user2357112 O dam true. Why is it doing that. Sorry i'm new.

Comment: @RNar Can you explain what you mean by "depanding on". is O(nlogn) faster than O(n)?

Comment: you are returning at your very first iteration. also, you should be using `zip`, not a nested `for`  loop

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990725/checking-strings-against-each-other-anagrams

Comment: The O(nlogn) of the sort is the least of your problems. If you are only comparing 2 words - who cares? The O(n*n) you will have for finding anagrams in a collections of words is a more interesting problem if you ask me

Comment: Even though sorted is O(nlogn), unless your strings are more than a million or so characters it's probably the fastest solution in Python anyway

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't even return a correct value. This one-liner is O(n log n):

```
return sorted(word1) == sorted(word2)
```

For an O(n) solution, you can count all characters:

```
from collections import Counter
# ...
def check(a, b)
  return Counter(a) == Counter(b)
```

Without collections it is much longer:

```
def check(a, b):
    chars = dict.fromkeys(a + b, 0)
    for c in a:
        chars[c] += 1
    for c in b:
        chars[c] -= 1
    return not any(chars.values())
```

This code does the following:

- `chars = dict.fromkeys(a + b, 0)`: Creates a dict, which has all the occurring characters in either word as keys set to 0.
- `for c in a: chars[c] += 1`: this will iterate over `a` and count the occurrences of each character in it. `chars` now contains the count of separate characters, (and some zeroes for characters in b but not a)
- `for c in b: chars[c] -= 1`: much the same as before, but instead this will subtract the character counts of `b` from `chars`
- `return not any(chars.values())`: `chars['h'] == 0` if and only if `a` and `b` has the same amount of `'h'`. This line checks if `chars` has only zeroes as values, meaning that all characters have the same count in both inputs. (as `any` returns if there is any truthy value in the sequence. 0 is falsy, every other integer is truthy.)

Both lists get iterated over once. Assuming O(1) access time for dictionaries makes the whole algorithm run in O(n) time (where n is the total length of the inputs). Space complexity is O(n) too (all characters can be distinct). Don't make that mistake when they ask you complexity. It's not necessary time complexity.

Comment: from collections import Counter

Comment: Ye my bad. I don't want to use collections though, I don't think the interviewer will like it. And the first solution isn't the fastest right?

Comment: @Angular: Internally python uses an O(n log n) algorithm for sorting, so yes, the first one is asymptotycally slower.

Comment: @Angular I don't know all the interviewers, but if I was one, I'd like people knowing the platform they're working on. Writing good algorithms is an important skill. Knowing the strengths of the platform you use is another.

Comment: You can simplify by initialising `chars = dict.fromkeys(a + b, 0)`

Comment: @JohnLaRooy yeah, let me think about that for a moment

Comment: @JohnLaRooy I was thinking about building two dicts for each string and then compare those. That would still need an inner function

Comment: @JohnLaRooy I don't know, allocating a new string.. but avoiding get-defaults... or make two dicts... I dont think any of these would count in real life, complexity in big O remains the same either... I let you decide that - if you feel that's somewhat better, please edit it.

Comment: I already did :) adding all the keys at once is probably also more time efficient than one at a time and probably enough to make up for the extra string object

Comment: Can someone explain step-by-step what's happening in the last code... let's say the a='cat' and b ='bob'.So you make a dict that looks like this
{'a':0,'t':0,'c':0,'b':0,'o':0}. I don't get the rest...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice option from http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/AlgorithmAnalysis/AnAnagramDetectionExample.html:

```
def anagramSolution(s1,s2):

    TABLE_SIZE = 128
    c1 = [0]*TABLE_SIZE
    c2 = [0]*TABLE_SIZE

    for ch in s1:
        pos = ord(ch)
        c1[pos] = c1[pos] + 1

    for ch in s2:
        pos = ord(ch)
        c2[pos] = c2[pos] + 1

    j = 0
    stillOK = True
    while j<TABLE_SIZE and stillOK:
        if c1[j]==c2[j]:
            j = j + 1
        else:
            stillOK = False

    return stillOK
```

This runs in O(n). Essentially, you loop over both strings, counting the occurrences of each letter. In the end, you can simply iterate over each letter, making sure the counts are equal.

As noted in the comments, this will have a harder time scaling for unicode. If you expect unicode, you would likely want to use a dictionary.

Comment: I think this answer has value because it is the no-import homework solution. however, no need to keep looping once `stillOK` is `False`. You can simply return `False` at this point.

Comment: Indeed. The loop will terminate once stillOk is set to False. See `while j<26 and stillOK:`

Comment: so ord is a built in function, that returns the ASCII character or each letter or something?

Comment: That is correct. Which raises a good point, this assumes the strings are lower case. If they were upper-case, it will not work as expected. You could make the array twice as big to account for upper-case letters, subtracting `ord('A')` from each. You could also use a dictionary, only storing the characters you encounter. In the end you would then have to loop over the keys.

Comment: requires modification even for capital letters

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I fixed that. Granted, if you wanted to support anything other than the OG ASCII chart, you would need to grow the size of the list.

Comment: What is the  ord(s2[i])-ord('a') used for?

Comment: That is used to set the index to the ASCII value. It was based at ord('a'), which is 97. By doing this any instance of 'a' would be indexed at 0, 'b' at 1, and so on. I modified this to allow for more letters. As has been pointed out, there are quite a few unicode characters, so it is worth considering how this solution would scale.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it like this without imports:

```
def count_occurences(mystring):
    occs = {}
    for char in mystring:
        if char in occs:
            occs[char] += 1
        else:
            occs[char] = 1
    return occs

def is_anagram(str1, str2):
    return count_occurences(str1) == count_occurences(str2)
```

Or, if you can use imports, just not a `Counter`, use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def count_occurences(mystring):
    occs = defaultdict(int)
    for char in mystring:
        occs[char] += 1

    return occs

def is_anagram(str1, str2):
    return count_occurences(str1) == count_occurences(str2)
```