# Checking if a string is anagram of each other

Tags: python-3.x

I have written the logic of checking if two strings are anagrams of each other in Python. Can someone please check if this is correct or is there a better way out:

```
def checkanagram(str1,str2):
    l1 = list(str1)
    l2 = list(str2)
    temp = str1
    for c in temp:
        if c in l2:
            l1.remove(c)
            l2.remove(c)
    if len(l1) == 0 and len(l2) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

str1 = input()
str2 = input()
if checkanagram(str1,str2):
    print ("It is an anagram")
else:
    print ("Its not an anagrams")
```

Comment: `return sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking strings against each other (Anagrams)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990725/checking-strings-against-each-other-anagrams)

Comment: What do your tests say? Does it work correctly for carefully chosen test cases?

Comment: Yes my tests are working fine. But i am wondering what will happen for big strings