# Creating an anagram function

Tags: python

Been trying to figure this out for two hours or so, can't seem to figure out how to create an anagram function without using sorted(). Trying to figure it out without using splice, .find(), .count(), .replace(), and sorted().
Currently what I have which works:

```
def anagram(anag1, anag2):
    if (sorted(anag1) == sorted(anag2)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

If anybody has a way to do it without sorted that would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking strings against each other (Anagrams)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990725/checking-strings-against-each-other-anagrams)

Comment: @Mason Desconi, you may consider accepting the answer that helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Counter`](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/collection/python-collections-counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def anagram(str_1, str_2):
   return Counter(str_1) == Counter(str_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `all` with a generator inside checking equality:

```
def anagram(anag1, anag2):
    if all(len([i for a in anag1 if a == i]) == len([i for b in anag2 if b == i]) for x in zip(anag1,anag2) for i in x):
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(anagram('car','arc'))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Sadly, I'm not able to use the sort method... If I could it would be a lot easier.

Comment: @MasonDesconi Edited my answer

Comment: Ack, you got a better one than me. Just return the result of the `all`, though.

Comment: @Multihunter Lol

Comment: @MasonDesconi Why are you unupvoting everyone

Comment: He asked for a solution that didn't use `.count()`. It was my un-upvote. Sorry.

Comment: @Multihunter Now?

Answer (score 0):

I like the `sorted` approach in your question as well as the `collections.Counter` approach better, but if you are just looking for alternatives you could use `re.findall` to determine whether each character in the first word occurs with the same frequency in the second word.

For example:

```
import re

def is_anagram(a, b):    
    return all(re.findall(c, a) == re.findall(c, b) for c in a)

print(is_anagram('cinema', 'iceman'))
#True
```

Comment: Edited answer with alternative approach based on good comment from @AdamSmith that identified flaw in original approach (see the original in the edit history for context).

Answer (score 0):

using counter make dictionary of each input string after that we can compare those dictionaries if there is no any difference, it's anagram otherwise not.

```
from collections import Counter

def anagram(ang1,ang2):

    count_list1 = Counter(ang1)
    count_dict1 = dict(count_list1)

    count_list2 = Counter(ang2)
    count_dict2 = dict(count_list2)

    dict_compare_length = len(count_dict1.items() - count_dict2.items())

    if dict_compare_length==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(anagram('listen','silen'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to see a solution without any fancy collections or functions. Just primitive data types, loops and conditions. So, how about...

```py
def count(word):
  map = {}
  for e in word:
    if e not in map:
      map[e] = 0
    map[e] += 1
  return map

def anagram(a, b):
  c1 = count(a)
  c2 = count(b)
  return all(c1[k] == c2[k] for k in c1)
```

Make a dictionary that lists the number of each element, then compares that there's the same number in both.