# Anagram string in python

Tags: python, string

Logic which I used to find anagram is as following

first I stored characters of first string in empty array

then I checked one by one if the characters of string2 is present already present in arr which i created

if yes then remove if no then append

at the end if whole of the array is empty then yes string is anagram else not

```
  t=int(input())
  for i in range(t):
      n1=input()
      n2=input()
      arr=[]


  for ch in n1:
      arr.append(ch)
  for ch in n2:
      if ch in arr:

          arr.pop(ch)
      else:

          arr.append(ch)
  if arr==[]:
      print("yes")
  else:
      print("no")
```

with this code the error is comming out to be

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
how do i rectify this error

Comment: Check what argument `list.pop` expects, and compare that with what  your code provides it, then consider using `list.remove` instead.

Comment: Which line of code is the error on? And please include the actual code. This code seems to mix up `n1` and `s1`, for example.

Comment: you have posted this question before it was closed now you have posted it again with another account

Comment: are you trying to solve your problem or expecting a better answer this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14990938/9050514

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because the `list.pop` waits `integer` type but it gets `string`. You should use the `list.remove`, it can handle the `string` type (It removes only the first occurrence of element, so the duplicated characters cannot cause turbulence). I have written a little example.

**Code:**

```
n1 = input("First word: ")
n2 = input("Second word: ")
arr = []

for ch in n1:
    arr.append(ch)
for ch in n2:
    if ch in arr:
        arr.remove(ch)
    else:
        arr.append(ch)
if not arr:  # True if the list is empty.
    print("Anagram")
else:
    print("NOT Anagram")
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
First word: hello
Second word: lelab
NOT Anagram

>>> python3 test.py
First word: hello
Second word: oelhl
Anagram
```