# python function does not return any values when checking for anagram

Tags: python, python-3.x

Team,

any hint what am i missing? am checking if two strings are anagram and get no result

```
# sol1 
def anagram_from_identical_chars(s1,s2):
    s1 = s1.replace(' ','').lower()
    s2 = s2.replace(' ','').lower()
    return sorted(s1) == sorted(s2)
anagram_from_identical_chars('add','dad')
```

output:
empty

expected

```
True
```

Comment: Maybe you need to print your returned value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is returning the output of a function different from printing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750136/how-is-returning-the-output-of-a-function-different-from-printing-it)

Comment: why is there a -5 to my post? am new to python sometimes other posts don't help everyone.

Comment: Related: [*"Checking strings against each other (Anagrams)"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990725)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `print` will be enough:

```
def anagram_from_identical_chars(s1,s2):
    s1 = s1.replace(' ','').lower()
    s2 = s2.replace(' ','').lower()
    return sorted(s1) == sorted(s2)

print(anagram_from_identical_chars('add','dad'))
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong you need to leave a line between the `return` statement and the `print` statement

Comment: @GAP2002 are you serious?

Comment: yes run this in your terminal you will get a syntax error

Comment: works. thanks for print prointer. space had nothing to do though. it worked without having to insert space.

Comment: @GAP2002 absolutely not. Your statement has not the slightest foundation, I'm sorry

Comment: `File "<stdin>", line 5`
 `print(anagram_from_identical_chars(s1,s2))`
`    ^`
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

For me

Comment: @GAP2002 Could be a problem with your compiler, certainly not the code. Try copying and pasting on https://repl.it/languages/python3 and see. Where are you trying to run it?

Comment: I'm running it in Python 3.9 from my terminal

Comment: @LorenzoZane He's pasting it into his command-line interpreter. Your code is correct, it's just a quirk of how it determines when code-blocks are terminated.

Comment: @LorenzoZane as Hampus Larsson said it is correct and it is a quirk, however, I am not wrong. PEP8 style guide [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) explains more, but you should leave a blank line to make the code more readable although it does "work" without doing so.

Comment: @GAP2002 Style guide != Syntax of a language. Your statements about his code was factually incorrect.