# How do I make a function that returns a list of anagrams of words passed as a parameter, found in a pre-defined lexicon?

Tags: python, anagram

I am given a pre-defined lexicon saved in an external file, which is a list of words sorted from a to z.
I am then asked to make a function, which takes a word as a parameter and returns a list of all the anagrams of that word found in the lexicon stated above.
Edit: I cannot use the set() or sorted() functions or import modules.
My code :

```
from lexicon import LEXICON
def anagrams(word):
    list=[]
    for i in range(len(LEXICON)):
        if i == word:
            if i in [i+1 : len(LEXICON)]:
                list.append(i)
    return list
```

Comment: Create a dictionary from the frozenset of the counts of the letters in each word to a list of those words, then just use that dictionary

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Indeed, that's what I thought too but at this current part of the exercice I am not allowed to use a dictionnary, because that method  is required in another exercise .

Comment: @sbeve Please [edit] the question to mention that. BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) as well as [ask], more generally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking strings against each other (Anagrams)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990725/checking-strings-against-each-other-anagrams)

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you for welcoming me! I have seen that question and it does not apply into my case though :( . I have already checked if there were any questions related to my issue as I didn't want to flood the thread with already answered questions. Although I am new to this page I understand asking already resolved questions can be annoying. I guess it can't be helped because the people in here have too much knowledge of the language as to our course we've only been through lists,dictionnaries,tuples, but not yet sets, but I've learned about it from practicing it on my own.

Comment: @sbeve Did you read all the answers? If I understand correctly, the [`sorted()` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14990938/4518341) should work for you. If it doesn't work for you, please edit your question to explain why.

Comment: I removed my answer about generating permutations because i realized that for longer words it would possibly lead to the number of permutations being bigger than the number of words in the lexicon which would add a substantial amount of time to the algorithm compared to just iterating through all items in the lexicon and compare the words against the input.