# How can I get the value of multiple elements while searching a dict efficiently? (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, find, anagram

How can I search any given txt file for anagrams and display the anagrams for every word in that file.

So far I can read the file, extract every single word and alphabetically sort every single word. I've tried making two dicts one dict containing the actual words in the text file as keys and the alphabetically sorted version of the words as values, and another dict of the dictionary file I have that is set up the same way.

Using both these dictionaries I've been unable to find an efficient way to get the following output for every word in the input list:

```
'eerst':  steer reste trees
```

If I try to loop through all the words in the given list, and inside each loop, loop inside the dictionary, looking and recording the anagrams, it takes too much time and is very inefficient. If I try the following:

```
for x in input_list:
    if x in dictionary:
        print dictionary[x]
```

I only get the first anagram of every word and nothing else.
If that made any sense, any suggestions would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Can you show more of your current code? I'm not sure that I understand what the two dictionaries you're describing are, which makes the question hard to follow. (I'm not downvoting though, that's somebody else.)

Comment: It's hard to tell from the question what you're using, but the ideal structure for this is a dictionary where the key is the sorted letters and the value is a list of words. eg `{"dgo": ["dog", "god"]}`. Can you edit the question with more detail?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238553/large-anagram-search-not-reading-to-end-of-set-python/19238642#19238642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if what I'm thinking of is what you're currently doing in your code, but I can't think of anything better:

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = 'dog god steer reste trees dog fred steer'.split() # or words from a file

unique_words = set(words)
anagram_dict = defaultdict(list)
for word in unique_words:
    key = "".join(sorted(word))
    anagram_dict[key].append(word)

for anagram_list in anagram_dict.values():
    if len(anagram_list) > 1:
        print(*anagram_list)
```

This will print (in arbitrary order):

```
god dog
steer trees reste
```

If you wanted to get the dictionary key value, you could make the final loop be over the `items` rather than the `values` of `anagram_dict` (and you could print out words that don't have any anagrams like `'fred'` in the example above, if you wanted). Note that thanks to the `set`, duplicates of words are not sorted multiple times.

Running time should be `O(M + U*N*log(N))` where `M` is the number of words, `U` is the number of unique ones and `N` is their average length. Unless you're sorting an organic chemistry textbook or something else that has lots of long words, it should be pretty close to linear in the length of the input.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to append multiple values to each key using regular dictionaries, and was getting errors.  

defaultdict solved that problem, but do you mind explaining why it allows me to do something I'm not allowed to do with a regular dictionary, how is it different?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get anagrams using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
words = list_of_words

for k, g in groupby(sorted(words, key=sorted), key=sorted):
    g = list(g)
    if len(g) > 1:
        print(g)
```

The big-O complexity isn't quite as good as the usual dictionary of lists approach, but it's still fairly efficient and it sounds funny when you read it out loud