# Python: Check if all characters from a word exists in a string in any order

Tags: python

I want to check if two strings are anagrams. For example, if my word is "halo", I want to check if those letters appear in "loha". It should match because it's an anagram.

My attempt fails and I'm not sure why. My code and output is below. I have a list of words and I want to check to see which elements are anagrams in the list.

```
def anagram(myList):
    for elem in myList:
        chars = set(elem)
        if all((c in chars) for c in myList):
            print  "Yes, anagram ", elem, chars
        else:
            print "NOT anagram ", elem, chars


wordsList = ["halo", "loha", "ahlo", "sully"]
anagram(wordsList)
```

And here's my output

```
NOT anagram  halo set(['a', 'h', 'l', 'o'])
NOT anagram  loha set(['a', 'h', 'l', 'o'])
NOT anagram  ahlo set(['a', 'h', 'l', 'o'])
NOT anagram  sully set(['y', 's', 'u', 'l'])
```

Comment: sets remove duplicates. Are you sure that's the kind of functionality you want?

Comment: [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)s are the best data structures for this

Comment: @coldspeed No it's not, I forgot about that. What should I use instead?

Comment: Is the expected output yes if all words are anagrams of each other, and no other wise? Also, you can iterate strings as is (letter by letter is default).

Comment: `c` takes the value `"halo"`, `"loha"` etc. Not individual characters. So `(c in chars)` is always false.

Comment: @kabanus for now, I just want to see which words are anagrams of eachother. I'll group likely group anagrams later

Comment: Related/dupe: [Using Python, find anagrams for a list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286554/using-python-find-anagrams-for-a-list-of-words)

Comment: I suggest (in the pedagogical spirit) you first try to make a function that gets two words and returns whether those are anagrams. If you just want the answer that's fine also. Looks like @Pault got you started, I see now.

Comment: _I want to check if two strings are anagrams_ If you only want to check two strings, why are you passing the entire word list to `anagram()`?

Comment: @JohnGordon The subproblem would be to check two strings. The bigger problem I'm trying to solve is checking in a list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python, find anagrams for a list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286554/using-python-find-anagrams-for-a-list-of-words)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should prove to be relatively fast in that it keeps a sorted list so it only has to make ONE new one every time it iterates.

```
from itertools import islice

def anagram(myList):
    s1 = sorted(myList[0])
    for i,elem in enumerate(islice(myList,1,len(myList))):
        s2 = sorted(elem)
        if s1 == s2:
            print ("Yes anagram: ",myList[i],elem)
        else:
            print ("Not anagram: ",myList[i],elem)
        s1 = s2

wordsList = ["halo", "loha", "ahlo", "sully"]
anagram(wordsList)
```

result:

```
Yes anagram:  halo loha
Yes anagram:  loha ahlo
Not anagram:  ahlo sully
```

Different structure option:

```
from itertools import islice

def is_anagram(sorted_1,sorted_2):
    if sorted_1 == sorted_2:
        return True
    return False

wordsList = ["halo", "loha", "ahlo", "sully"]

s1 = sorted(wordsList[0])
for i,elem in enumerate(islice(wordsList,1,len(wordsList))):
    s2 = sorted(elem)
    if is_anagram(s1,s2):
        print ("Yes anagram: ",wordsList[i],elem)
    else:
        print ("Not anagram: ",wordsList[i],elem)
    s1 = s2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def isanagram(ele1,ele2):
    ele1=list(ele1)
    ele2=list(ele2)
    return(sorted(ele1)==sorted(ele2))

print(isanagram("ahlo", "halo"))
```

Out put

> True

**For multiple elements check**

```
print(map(isanagram,["ahlo", "halo"],[ "alho", "sully"])
```

Out put

> [True, False]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `counter` which outputs a dictionary of letter counts for each letter in a word

```
from Collections import Counter

word1='halo'
word2='hola'

if Counter(word1) == Counter(word2):
   print 'Yes Anagram {} {}'.format(word1,word2)
else :
   print 'Not Anagram {} {}'.format(word1,word2)
```

Comment: I see that this is more efficent

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `sorted()` on both strings and compare them.

```
def is_anagram(str1, str2):
   return sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)

k = is_anagram('angel', 'glean')
if k == True:
   print('Strings are anagrams')
else:
   print('Strings are not anagrams')
```

Here, `sorted('angel')` outputs `['a', 'e', 'g', 'l', 'n']` and `sorted('glean')` also outputs `['a', 'e', 'g', 'l', 'n']`. Both equal, hence are **anagrams**.

To make things clear:

```
>>> sorted('angel') 
['a', 'e', 'g', 'l', 'n'] 
>>> sorted('glean') 
['a', 'e', 'g', 'l', 'n'] 
>>> sorted('angel') == sorted('glean') 
True
```

**Solution to your problem:**

```
def is_anagram(str1, str2):
   return sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)

wordsList = ["halo", "loha", "ahlo", "sully"]
each = wordsList[0]
for another in wordsList:
   if each != another:
      k = is_anagram(each, another)
      if k == True:
         print('{} and {} are anagrams'.format(each, another))
      else:
         print('{} and {} are not anagrams'.format(each, another))
```

**Output:**

```
halo and loha are anagrams
halo and ahlo are anagrams
halo and sully are not anagrams
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all the angrams in your list, you might want to do this instead:

```
# Checks if two strings are anagrams
def isAnagram(str1, str2):
    return sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)

# Iterates over all items in your list and compares it with all other items to check if they are anagrams.
def anagrams(myList):
    for i in range(0,len(myList)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(myList)):
            if isAnagram(myList[i], myList[j]):
                print "Yes anagram: ", myList[i], myList[j]
            else:
                print "Not anagram: ", myList[i], myList[j]

wordsList = ["halo", "loha", "ahlo", "sully"]
anagram(wordsList)
```

This would return the following:

```
Yes anagram: halo loha
Yes anagram: halo ahlo
Not anagram: halo sully
Yes anagram: loha ahlo
Not anagram: loha sully
Not anagram: ahlo sully
```

This may not be the most efficient solution but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Use sets:

```
set('hola')==set('loha')
```

outputs True

As noted in the comments, this will not work even with a len parameter attached.
Here's a recursive anagram test to redeem myself

```
`def anagram(string1,string2):
if string1=='' or string2== '':
    if string1!='' or string2!='':
        return False
    else:
        return True
if len(string1)!=len(string2) or set(string1)!=set(string2):
    return False
stemp1 = list(string1)
stemp2 = list(string2)
stemp2.remove(stemp1[0])
return anagram(''.join(stemp1[1:]),''.join(stemp2))`
```

Comment: This fails for `set('marg')==set('grammar') >> True`.

Comment: just put a parameter before like `if len('marg'')==len('grammar'):` or add it to the logical:  `set('marg')==set('grammar') and len('marg')==len('grammar') >>false ` and boom universal anagram testing

Comment: Nope. It would still not be able to tell the difference between `grammar` and `agmrrrr`. Read the [documentation on `set`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for the reason.

Comment: I see the reason.  You've bypassed the len parameter by making strings of the same len made up of different counts of characters.  No need to read set docs but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below code takes a list of words as input and groups them into anagrams

```
def is_grouped(word, anagram_groups):
    is_grouped = False
    for group in anagram_groups:
        if word in group:
            print "{0} is already part of anagram group={1}".format(word, group)
            is_grouped = True
            break
    return is_grouped

def get_anagram_group(word_to_check, word_to_check_index, wordlist):
    word_to_check_as_list = list(word_to_check)
    word_to_check_as_list.sort()
    group = [word_to_check]
    for i in range(0, len(wordlist)):
        if not i == word_to_check_index:
            word = wordlist[i]
            word_as_list = list(word)
            word_as_list.sort()
            if word_as_list == word_to_check_as_list:
                group.append(word)   
    return group

def group_anagrams(wordlist):
    anagram_groups = []
    for i in range(0, len(wordlist)):

        word_under_test = wordlist[i]
        # check if the word's anagrams already identified as part of anagram group
        anagramed = is_grouped(word_under_test, anagram_groups)
        if not anagramed:
            # if word not already a part of anagram group then find find all anagrams for the word
            anagram_group = get_anagram_group(word_under_test, i, wordlist)
            if len(anagram_group) == 1:
                print "no anagrams found for word {0}".format(word_under_test)
            else:
                print "anagrams found for word {0}={1}".format(word_under_test, anagram_group)
                anagram_groups.append(anagram_group)
    return anagram_groups



wlist = ['aloha' , 'hoala', 'loaha', '123', '321', 'xya']
print group_anagrams(wlist)
```

output:

```
anagrams found for word aloha=['aloha', 'hoala', 'loaha']
hoala is already part of anagram group=['aloha', 'hoala', 'loaha']
loaha is already part of anagram group=['aloha', 'hoala', 'loaha']
anagrams found for word 123=['123', '321']
321 is already part of anagram group=['123', '321']
no anagrams found for word xya
[['aloha', 'hoala', 'loaha'], ['123', '321']]
```